# Adding JLabel to JMenuBar and making it take up all available space

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu

I'm working on an application with a dropdown JMenuBar. I've decided I want to remove the outer frame though as I don't like how it looks. So I've added a minimize, maximize and an exit button to the JMenuBar like this after I add the menu's:

```
//buttons
this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

//turn into images later
minimize = new JButton(" - ");
maximize = new JButton(" [] ");
exit = new JButton(" x ");

this.add(minimize);
this.add(maximize);
this.add(exit);
```

Now to make the JMenuBar dragable I want to add a JLabel in between the JMenuItems and these buttons, However I don't know how I can get it to use all available space there. Just adding it like this doesn't work:

```
//draglabel
dragLabel = new JLabel("hey");
dragLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);
dragLabel.setOpaque(true);
this.add(dragLabel);
```

How can I maximize this JLabel to take upp all avaiable space inside the JMenuBar?

Comment: `Now to make the JMenuBar dragable I want to add a JLabel in between the JMenuItems and these buttons` - why do you need the label? Just add the dragging code to the menubar itself. Check out [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a class to help with the dragging.

Comment: I believe that will also block access to all the buttons and JMenu dropdowns

Comment: Why would you think this? The point is to actually try it first BEFORE making an assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JPanel instead of JLabel. It stretches to fill all available space by default. If you are adamant about using Jlabel you will have to extend it and override getMaximumSize() method like this:

```
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label") {
// Maximum size should be larger than what the JMenuBar will ever be.
    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: The red area is the JPanel but it does not seem to go all the way to the right.

Comment: @BRHSM You probabbly added both HorizontalGlue and JPanel to the JMenuBar. the glue took half the available space and the panel took the other half.